# jQuery Validation Plugin doesn't work on form in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I am trying to validate a form on the frontend of a page in WordPress. I use the last version of jQuery Validation plugin, but it doesn't validate the form and submit it even if the rules are not being followed.

As you can see below, it's not a problem with the type or name of the inputs.

Is it possible that Bootstrap is conflicting with the jQuery plugin? What could be causing this?

The form:

```
<form action='<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>' class="form-subscriber" method="POST" id="form-subscriber-details">
        <?php if( isset( $process_details_message )){ ?>
            <div class="<?php echo 'alert alert-' . $process_details_message['type']; ?>" role="alert">
                <ul href="#" class="alert-link">
                    <?php 
                        foreach ($process_details_message['message'] as $key => $value) {
                    ?>
                        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                    <?php
                        }  
                    ?> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newsletter_signature_email"><?php esc_html_e('Email Address', 'work-theme'); ?></label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="newsletter_signature_email" id="newsletter_signature_email" placeholder="Email:" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newsletter_signature_name"><?php esc_html_e('Name', 'work-theme'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newsletter_signature_name" id="newsletter_signature_name" placeholder="Name:" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <?php foreach ( get_job_listing_categories() as $cat ) : ?>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cat->name, 'work-theme' ); ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="" required>
                        <?php esc_html_e('I want to receive promotional emails.', 'work-theme'); ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value='details_newsletter_signature')>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'details_newsletter_signature', 'process_details_nonce' ); ?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php esc_html_e('Submit', 'work-theme'); ?>">

        </form>
```

The Javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery('#form-subscriber-details').validate({
    errorClass: "error",
    rules: {
        'newsletter_signature_name': {
            required: true
        },
        'newsletter_signature_email': {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        console.log("Submitted!") 
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: How are you loading the script?

Comment: @j08691 I updated the code to show how it is on the site. In my functions.php, I am also enqueue jQuery and jQuery Validation as dependecies for this code, so they are loaded before it,